# What are some of the simplest applications of heavy hitter problem?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, streaming-algorithm

I am learning about stream algorithms and am implementing Count-Min sketch data structure. I am also learning to approximately solve the HH problem with sublinear space complexity.

I want to know what are some of the basic applications of HH problem.